# eclim (eclipse + vim) auto-completion

Tags: java, eclim

When I use eclim's auto-completion features in headless mode, it opens the regular auto-completion little window but also opens a separate scratch preview window to show the overloaded functions. How can I not let the scratch window show up? (like just have everything in the little auto-completion window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set cot-=preview
```

in ur vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Also could do the following your vimrc

```
set cot=menu
```